I get this error data:image/png;base64,[object Object] when i load image from Mongodb
I have a html table, where I do data from MongoDB but the image has refused to show, and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.
here is what i have done so far.
here is the js code to get the image and the data from the client and send to the backend server
app.post('/newInt_ImgUpload', upload.array('inventoryImg', 3), async (req, res) => {
    //console.log(req.files);
    //console.log(req.body);
    const cookies = req.headers.cookie;
    const jwtToken = cookies.split("=")[1].split(";")[0];
    //console.log(jwtToken);
    if (!jwtToken) {
        console.log('app crashed at line 119: PersonalInfo');
        return res.sendStatus(401);
    }
    const refreshToken = jwtToken;

    const user = await userModel.findOne({RefreshToken: refreshToken}).exec()
    if(!user) return res.sendStatus(401);
    console.log('User was found');

    const count = new Uint32Array(1);

    try {
        const inventory = await inventoryModel.create({
            'UserId': user._id,
            'Name': req.body.ItemName,
            'DateAdded': date.format(now, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss').split(" ")[0],
            'Price': req.body.Price,
            'WeightKG': req.body.WeightKG,
            'Quantity': req.body.Quantity,
            'Description': req.body.Description,
            'image1': { 
                data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/uploads/' + req.files[0].filename)).toString('base64'),
                contentType: req.files[0].mimetype
            },
            'image2': { 
                data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/uploads/' + req.files[1].filename)).toString('base64'),
                contentType: req.files[1].mimetype
            },
            'image3': { 
                data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/uploads/' + req.files[2].filename)).toString('base64'),
                contentType: req.files[2].mimetype
            },
            'Id': Math.trunc((crypto.getRandomValues(count))/1000000)
        });
        const result = await inventory.save();
        console.log(result);
        const inventoryActivitylog = await activityLogsModel.create({
            'UserId': user._id,
            'Date': date.format(now, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss').split(" ")[0],
            "Time": date.format(now, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss').split(" ")[1],
            'Status':  "Inventory updated."
        });
        await inventoryActivitylog.save();

        req.files.forEach(files => {
            fs.unlink(path.join(__dirname + '/uploads/' + files.filename), (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                //console.log('Image deleted');
              });
        })
        console.log("All images deleted")
        //res.redirect('/userProfile');
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Inventory updated and images processed' });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

after that has been done, the code below loads each time to the page that shows the table data, but the image refuses to show and give the following error: data:image/png;base64,[object Object]
document.getElementById('allitems').addEventListener('click', async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/Inventory/allInventory/List', { 
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            credentials: 'include' 
        })

        .then(async response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`); 
            }
            return response.json();
            })
        .then(data => {
            const inventoryList = document.querySelector('.inventoryList');
        
            // Clear any existing rows
            inventoryList.innerHTML = '';

            // Loop through the fetched data and create new rows
            data.forEach(item => {
                console.log(item);
                const eachInventory = document.createElement('div');
                eachInventory.classList.add('eachInventory');

                const imgsrc = `data:${item.image1.contentType};base64,${item.image1.data}`;

                eachInventory.innerHTML = `
                    <div class="itemName">
                        <div><img src="${imgsrc}" alt=""></div>
                        <div><h4>${item.Name}</h4></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemDate"><h3>${new Date(item.DateAdded).toLocaleDateString()}</h3></div>
                    <div class="itemPrice"><h3>${item.Price.toLocaleString()}</h3></div>
                    <div class="itemQuantity"><h3>${item.Quantity}</h3></div>
                `;
                
                // Append the new row to the table
                inventoryList.appendChild(eachInventory);
            })
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
});

this is the image

Here is my Get /Inventory/allInventory/List
case "List":
            const Listuser = await UserModel.findOne({RefreshToken: refreshToken}).exec()
            const ListuserInventory = await inventoryModel.find({'UserId': Listuser._id}).exec()
            //console.log(ListuserInventory);
            if (ListuserInventory) {
                ListuserInventory.forEach(item => {
                    if (item.image1?.data) {
                        item.image1.data = item.image1.data.toString('base64');
                    }
                    if (item.image2?.data) {
                        item.image2.data = item.image2.data.toString('base64');
                    }
                    if (item.image3?.data) {
                        item.image3.data = item.image3.data.toString('base64');
                    }
                });
            }
            res.json(ListuserInventory);
        break;

frontend code /newInt_ImgUpload
document.getElementById('inventoryForm').addEventListener("submit", async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission
    
    // Create a FormData object from the form
    const form = document.getElementById('inventoryForm');
    const formData = new FormData(form);

    // You can check if required fields are filled in
    if (!formData.get('ItemName') || !formData.get('Price') || !formData.get('Quantity') || !formData.get('WeightKG') || !formData.get('Description')) {
        alert('Fill in the required Information(s)');
        return;
    }

    try {
        // Send the form data using fetch
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/newInt_ImgUpload', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            body: formData // Automatically handles file uploads
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            alert('Inventory Updated.');
            //window.location.href = '/userProfile';
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
});

so I tried to console.log the upload.array data that is sent to the backend, this is what i get [
{
    fieldname: 'inventoryImg',
    originalname: 'Screenshot 2024-01-03 080055.png',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/png',
    destination: 'uploads',
    filename: 'Screenshot 2024-01-03 080055.png',
    path: 'uploads\\Screenshot 2024-01-03 080055.png',
    size: 22593
  },


You've shown the backend code for POST /newInt_ImgUpload, and the frontend code for GET /Inventory/allInventory/List ... perhaps the code you haven't shown, i.e. frontend code for POST /newInt_ImgUpload or the backend code for GET /Inventory/allInventory/List is wrong

I'm not sure I understand what you mean. @JaromandaX

you have two requests ... a POST and a GET ... each request needs frontend (browser) and backend (server) code ... you've shown half the code - so it could be in the other half you're doing something wrong - my guess is it's the server code for GET /Inventory/allInventory/List that is wrong

oh! ok, i have included it now to my question @JaromandaX

you still haven't shown the frontend code for uploading the images to /newInt_ImgUpload - the issue may also be in your upload.array middleware ... something somewhere is changing the image data to the string "[object Object]" - this is usually the result of some .toString() call (implicit or explicit) on an Object

Done, I just included that now @JaromandaX

Sorry, I added to my comment ... at a quick glance, the code you have shown so far looks like it's not the cause of issue ...

Oh, wait. is upload.array multer middleware?

so I tried to console.log the upload,array data that is sent to the backend, this is what i get [
{
fieldname: 'inventoryImg',
originalname: 'Screenshot 2024-01-03 080055.png',
encoding: '7bit',
mimetype: 'image/png',
destination: 'uploads',
filename: 'Screenshot 2024-01-03 080055.png',
path: 'uploads\Screenshot 2024-01-03 080055.png',
size: 22593
},

what about item.image1?.data in ListuserInventory.forEach(item => {? is that the image data as expected?

by the way, it looks like your storing the images as base64, so there should be no need to convert them to base64 when sending in List

That error suggests that in the database document item.image1.data contains an object, not a string.

Your image is saved in base64 format. Instead of storing files in db prefer storing it in any external service. If you are using AWS you can use s3 bucket or if not using s3, you may try cloudflare image services, cloudinary etc.

I did similar to upload and display profile picture, and it worked, I'm not sure why it has refused to work this time.

are you using any editor like CKeditor or TinyMCE to convert text into html?
